# The kernel of this evaluation map.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider $$f: \mathbb{Z}[x] \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[2^{1/3}]$$ which is a evaluation map for $x = 2^{1/3}$.

Question: What is the kernel of $f$?

My work so far: I take the ideal $(x^3-2)$ as my answer, and I want to show that $\ker(f) = (x^3-2)$. One side is trivial, i.e., $(x^3-2) \subset \ker(f)$.

Any idea for the another inclusion?

Note that: $a_0 + 2a_3 + 4a_6 + 8a_9 + \dots = 0$, $a_1 + 2a_4 + 4a_7 + 8a_10 + \dots = 0$ and $a_2 + 2a_5 + 4a_8 + 8a_{11} + \dots = 0$ for any polynomial $p(x) = a_0 +a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots \in \ker(f)$. This can help but the proof is not very clean (or not a valid proof at all), i.e., I need to deal with different cases for $n=3k$, $n=3k-1$ or $n=3k-2$.

Well, thanks for the help!

Comment: Think about the properties of minimal polynomials. $2^\frac13$ is a root in a polynomial $p$ if and only if...

Comment: anything unclear ?

Comment: Compared to the concept of Krull dimension, I feel like the method of minimal polynomial is more approachable, but I don't know I am right or not. $2^{1/3}$ is a root in a polynomial $p$ if and only if $x^3-2$ divides the polynomial $p$ since $x^3-2$ is the minimal polynomial of $2^{1/3}$? @Milten

Comment: Is my argument above correct? But, why is $x^3-2$ the minimal polynomial of $2^{1/3}$? How do I show it? I am pretty new to the concept of minimal polynomial. Thanks. @reuns

Comment: If $f\in \Bbb{Q}[x], f(2^{1/3})=0$ and $x^3-2$ doesn't divide $f$ then $g=\gcd(f,x^3-2)\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ divides $x^3-2$ and $g\ne x^3-2,g \ne 1$ (because the complex $\gcd$ divides the rational $\gcd$, in fact both are equal) contradicting the irreducibility of $x^3-2$. This is why the kernel of $\Bbb{Q}[x]\to \Bbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is given by the minimal polynomial : the only irreducible monic polynomial $\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ with $\alpha$ in its roots

Comment: @Rookiecookie I wrote an answer now, that is basically an expansion of reuns's answer, where I keep it as concrete as possible. A lot of it can be generalised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in the comments, $2^\frac13$ is a root of $p\in \mathbb Q[x]$ if and only if the minimal polynomial of $2^\frac13$ divides $p$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Why is $x^3-2$ the minimal polynomial? Remember, the minimal polynomial is the monic rational polynomial of smallest degree that has $2^\frac13$ as a root. So, is $2^\frac13$ the root of any first- or second-degree rational polynomial? No, so $x^3-2$ is the minimal polynomial.

Alternatively, if we can show that $x^3-2$ is irreducible, then we also know that it is the minimal polynomial. Since it is of degree $\le 3$, it suffices to show that it has no rational roots, which is true because the only real root is $2^\frac13$. If you know Eisenstein's criterion, that also works here.

Now we can finish. Let $p\in\mathbb Z[x]$. Then
$$
p \in \ker f
\iff p(2^\frac13)=0
\iff p = q\cdot(x^3-2),\ q\in\mathbb Q[x]
$$
Remember that $p$ has integer coefficients. This forces $q$ to be in $\mathbb Z[x]$ as well. If not, then let $cx^k$ be the highest-degree term in $q$ where $c\notin\mathbb Z$. Then the $(k+3)$-degree term in $p$ will not be an integer; contradiction.

So we are done:
$$
p \in \ker f \iff p = q\cdot(x^3-2),\ q\in\mathbb Z[x] \iff p\in (x^3-2)
$$

Comment: That is pretty clear for me now, and thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

The kernel has to be a non-maximal prime ideal in  $\mathbf Z[x]$, and  $x^3-2$ is irreducible in  $\mathbf Z[x]$, hence, as it is a U.F.D., the ideal $x^3-2$ is prime, and  not maximal. Furthermore,  $\mathbf Z[x]$ has Krull dimension $2$, so non-zero, non-maximal prime ideals all have height $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I guess I need to learn the concept of Krull dimension for this question.

Answer (score 0):

From the polynomial gcd the kernel of $\Bbb{Q}[x]\to \Bbb{Q}[2^{1/3}]$ is a principal ideal $u\ \Bbb{Q}[x]$

Since $x^3-2$ has no root it is irreducible and $u=x^3-2$

Thus the kernel of $\Bbb{Z}[x]\to \Bbb{Z}[2^{1/3}]$ is $$(x^3-2)\Bbb{Q}[x]\cap \Bbb{Z}[x]= (x^3-2)\Bbb{Z}[x]$$

(for $u\in \Bbb{Z}[x]_{monic}$ and $v\in \Bbb{Q}[x],\not \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ then $uv\not \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$)